# ssis adding year to date of database with script component

Tags: ssis, script-component

i have a database with no year, only day and month (example 20-12). because of this, the database adds the year automatically. The problem with this is, that in some cases the year is ahead of time, for example 20-12-2020, while it's actually 2019.

example of the table:

order_number     date_of_order (original table)
1                20-12

how it looks when i add the database in ssms:

order_number    date_of_order
1               20-12-2020

What i want to do is add the right years to the day and month with scripts component. for example if the date is in the past, then make it 2019. If the date is in the future make it 2020.

[image: script component error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already starting with a date then you can just use a derived column to do your transformation:

Use this as formula similar to the c# above:

```
OrderDate > GETDATE() ? DATEADD("yy",-1,OrderDate) : OrderDate
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution helped me the most.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a path to move forward. You just need to separate the column into month and day numbers:

```
        //This will split out your date/month
        string OrigCol = "20-12"; //Replace this with Rows.YourColumnName
        string[] col = OrigCol.Split('-');
        int d = Int32.Parse(col[0]);
        int m = Int32.Parse(col[1]);

        DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, m, d);
        if (dt > DateTime.Now)
            dt = dt.AddYears(-1);

        //Set your new column to dt
```

This code will create a date with current year, and only subtract a year if the result is in the future.

If your column is already a date (with a 2020 default) you can jump straight into the if.

```
        DateTime dt = Row.YourColumnName;
        if (dt > DateTime.Now)
            dt = dt.AddYears(-1);

        //Set your new column to dt
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but i am getting the following error. See screenshot above.

Comment: the name OrigCol  is not in your code on the first line, but there's another issue. Your source is a date and not a string. I'll amend my answer to meet a date with 2020 always coming in instead of the string